# no data shown MySql php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

The problem that I am having now is that I will be getting duplicated data if My MySql tables have the data inside. However, if one of my tables is empty, all data is not able to be shown.

This is my code below:

```
$stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM applicantpersonaldetails apd "
        . "JOIN employementdetails ed ON apd.ApplicantID = ed.ApplicantID "
        . "JOIN sourceoffunds sof ON apd.ApplicantID = sof.ApplicantID "
        . "JOIN existingbankproducts ext ON apd.ApplicantID = ext.ApplicantID "
        . "WHERE apd.AccountID ='{$accountId}' AND applicantType ='joint1';");        

$stmt->execute();

if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        extract($row);

        echo $row['EmploymentStatus'];
        ?>
        <?php
    }
} else {
    ?>
    <div class="">
        <div class="alert alert-warning">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; No Data Found ...
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: I think you should read more about type of joins, difference among them at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `LEFT JOIN` if you want all rows, even non-matching ones:

```
SELECT *
FROM applicantpersonaldetails apd LEFT JOIN
     employementdetails ed
     ON apd.ApplicantID = ed.ApplicantID LEFT JOIN
     sourceoffunds sof
     ON apd.ApplicantID = sof.ApplicantID LEFT JOIN
     existingbankproducts ext
     ON apd.ApplicantID = ext.ApplicantID
WHERE apd.AccountID ='{$accountId}' AND applicantType = 'joint1';
```

Note:  It is not clear which table `applicantType` comes from.  If it is not from `apd`, then you might want to include it in the appropriate `ON` clause rather than in the `WHERE` clause.